# Are questions on estimation-accuracy, efficiency and productivity on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion

Wondering if question that deal with estimation methods, estimation accuracy, developer efficiency / productivity measurement, benchmarks etc., i.e. in context of software development, be considered 'on-topic' for SO ?

If not, could someone point me to a SE-site that might be more appropriate ?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com, I would have thought, if it's **specific to developers** (see e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productivity), otherwise http://workplace.stackexchange.com for more general employee productivity.